# Objects missing in render, light has no effect

Tags: rendering

I've been test-rendering a character I'm working on and I'm running into some problems. Not only are the eyes of my character not appearing in the render, but light seems to have no effect on objects at all.

In the viewport, all objects are visible and changes in light make changes to the image, but when I hit F12, I get the same thing every time.

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This is what it looks like when I hit F12

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is what it looks like when I hit F12:

http://i.imgur.com/kjvdfTE.png

Comment: Does going out from Local View before rendering fix your problem?

Comment: Carlo you nailed it! My last render matched the viewport render at last! I can't believe it was something this simple.

Comment: In the future please don't crop the images so tight. Keep the interface, there is valuable information there to troubleshoot without having to download the file.

Comment: how exactly does local view influence this? thats so weird.

Comment: @MadlainaKalunder Local view isolates selected objects from the rest of the scene for closer inspection. As such it also isolates it from the influence of lights and other elements in the scene.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos but this should be the case only for the lights created with Emission shader; lamps seem to overcome Local view limitation which is also mentioned in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/views.html#view-global-local) in the Note section. That's why the linked answer doesn't really work in that way for me.

Comment: Ah yes, it only seems to work for ´pure´ lamp objects. If it is a mesh with emission, o the lamp object is inside a group instance or dupli it will no longer work I think.

Answer (score 3):

### Object added in Local view don't update till you go out of it

I never notice, but looks like the object you build **while** you are in the Local view, despite being added to the outiner, (and so to the scene as well) they don't appear in the Global view till you go out from the local View.

At least this is what happens in 2.78 version.

If you open another window, you can examine the scene that is being rendered:

[image]

Eyes are missing, and maybe the planes that are providing light to the scene...all objects that you have probably built while you was in Local view without ever going out.

Those are not rendered because they are in a *limbo*, trapped in the Local view waiting to be released. That's where the difference cames from.

You can see how the cube added in the image sequence below is not in the Global till I go out from Local view.

[image]

I don't kown if this is a feature or a little bug.

Comment: If those light sources were added as lamps (Shift+A>Lamp) this won't be an issue as lamps continue light object even if local view is enabled but objects with Emission shader do not. This probably changed as of recent versions as [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19489/rendering-and-materials-are-black) doesn't appear to be the case if using lamps